# Changing ref to eqref

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, amsmath

I have plenty of equations in my Tex which were labeled with (`\ref{eqn: bla}`) which I now want to change to `\eqref{eqn: bla}`. Is there a fast way to do this rather than manually doing it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Suggestion: Use your editor and `search/replace`: `\ref{eqn:` by `\eqref{eqn:}` if your equation labels follow this pattern. A dirty way (not recommended (really)): `\let\ref\eqref` (Don't do this!!!)

Comment: The space in `eqn: bla` isn't recommended too ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer that may not work because of the parenthesis surrounding \ref{}

Comment: $\ref$??? Does not look healthy!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- i think the parentheses belong inside the backticks; they're part of the input.

Comment: if you have any other `\ref`s in your document, the only way i can suggest is a search-and-replace to check them one by one; an emacs keyboard macro could do this handily, if boringly time-comsuming.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. I thought so that there is no more efficient way.

Comment: @bissi: Are all your equation labels using the `eqn:` prefix?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes. and all have the round parenthesis around them which I manually inserted.

Comment: @bissi: Sorry, but you've shot yourself into your own foot with those manual parentheses ;-)

Comment: there still another way: search replace as @ChristianHupfer first comment  `(\ref{eq->\eqref{eq` and than redefine `\eqref` to eat the 2nd parenthese)

Comment: @touhami: That's another way yes, but I still think that using `regexp` would be easier? With `sed` or `perl`...

Comment: @touhami: You're are an TeX expert: Is it possible to make `(` and `)` active, look ahead if `\ref{..}` comes an then react accordingly?

Comment: May  I suggest regular expressions? I don't know about other editors except Emacs, but under Windows, `WinEdt` can handle regular expressions.

Comment: @Bernard: I think **even** vi knows regular expressions ...

Comment: Surely. I meant dedicated TeX editors such as TeXmaker and the like.

Answer (score 3):

If there wouldn't be manual `(...)` parentheses, one could use a `\ref` wrapper command that checks whether the reference label name contains `eqn:` and use `\eqref` accordingly. But alas,... this is no solution for the `(...)` case.

**Note** I am not sure this will work in conjunction with `cleveref` or `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\let\origref\ref  % Prevent recursive definition

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{%
  \textup{\tagform@{\origref{#1}}}%
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{%
  \IfSubStr{#1}{eqn:}{%
    \eqref{#1}%
  }{%
    \origref{#1}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\section{First} \label{sec:first}



\begin{equation}
  E=mc^2 \label{eqn: bla}
\end{equation}

\section{Second} \label{sec:second}

In section \ref{sec:first} we have equation \ref{eqn: bla}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I will just let it pass and "settle" for my fate with \ref.

Comment: @bissi -- i don't know whether this will cause you to rethink, but it's worth mentioning that `\eqref` enforces `\upshape`, including the parentheses, so that they will not be sloped in xrefs in theorems and other italic environments.  how `\ref` is styled is dependent on the document class. and may or may not be compatible in appearance.